# Is membership in the index 2 subgroup of $Sp_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$ detected by a polynomial in the matrix entries?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I learned from Magma that $Sp_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$ has an index-2 subgroup isomorphic to $A_6$. Is it possible, given a matrix $M\in Sp_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$, to detect membership in this subgroup using a polynomial in the matrix entries? If so, what is the polynomial?

**Edit:** Mariano points out below that actually any function from $Sp_4(\mathbb{F}_2)\subset M_4(\mathbb{F}_2)$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a polynomial, so in particular the indicator of my desired subgroup is a polynomial.

But is there a *nice* polynomial that does the trick? Apologies for the softness of this; but I mean to avoid the polynomial that I obtain by enumerating the elements of the subgroup in question and then just constructing the polynomials that serve as the indicators for each and then summing them. I would like the polynomial to illuminate the subgroup in some way. I am eager for your thoughts about this.

Comment: Every function from that group to F_2 is equal to a polynomial,  no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - Because it is the restriction of some function from $M_4(\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2^{16}$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$ and every such is a polynomial? Yes I guess you're right. But what's the polynomial???

Comment: An obvious way to make "nice" more precise is to let either the parameter $4$ or the parameter $2$ vary and ask for a uniform answer in the parameter. I don't know if there is one though. Maybe some symplectic analogue of the Dickson invariant?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Unfortunately you cannot change the $4$ or the $2$ because these values are exceptional ${\rm Sp}(2n,q)$ is a perfect group for all other values of $(n,q)$ with $n \ge 4$.

Comment: That seems like a pretty strong argument against there being a nice answer to this question, then.